# Gherkins of Gherkins

Tags: selenium, cucumber, gherkin

I am using cucumber and selenium, I have my Gherkin files. Is there any way that in cucumber I can use Gherkins of Gherkins. Where I have one step def and for that step def I can define a kind of sub-step defs in another Gherkins file.

Example:

```
Given I login to amazon 
And I search for book "core java"
And I select core java book
And I add it in cart
And I place order
```

Instead of writing these many step defs is there any way where I can say like:

```
Given I login to Amazon
And I place order for book "core java"
```

in my main feature file I just define the above two lines where my sub-steps are in some other feature file.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for nested steps: https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/defining-steps/nested-steps

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: I am able to do this with Selenium and cucumber where I have created another layer on top of my gherkins where I define my scenario in more business language and  internally I convert that Business language in standard Gherkins. Thanks for suggestions but I am able to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi Rozer, Could please let me know how you achieved it?

Answer (score 0):

Calling steps from another step is not supported in Gherkin.

What you can do is to create a helper method that you can call from multiple steps. This will most likely remove the urge to call a step from another step as it will be easy to call this common helper instead. And as calling a step from another step in Gherkin isn't supported, you don't really have that choice.